# Y Position appear to be different although y is set to a constant value (Swift Sprite)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift4

I am making a game where blocks (the enemy) are hard coded to a y value of 500 and have a random x value. I have two blocks, one that is a SKSpriteNode and another one which is a copy of the SKSpriteNode, each block has their own function, addEnemy() and addEnemyCopy()

When I run the game I see that the blocks are being spawned at different y values even though they are both hardcoded to a y value of 500. I printed out the positions of both blocks and I saw that sometimes the two blocks were being spawned at a y value of 500 and sometimes they were being spawned at a y value of around 400 or 300. Why is this happening? I have the y value set to 500, so the block should always be spawning at 500 on the y axis and then be spawning at a random value on the x axis. Both blocks are spawning at a random X value so that part works fine, I do realize that sometimes the blocks spawn off screen, but ignore that for now.

Here's the code relevant:

original enemy function:

```
    func addEnemy() {

    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(size.width - enemy.size.width)), y: 500)
    print("Enemy position: ")
    print(enemy.position)
    enemy.zPosition = 1
    enemy.setScale(0.4)

    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemy.texture!, size: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2

    self.addChild(enemy)


    let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(y: player.position.y - 300, duration: 1)
    let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let enemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, deleteEnemy])
    enemy.run(enemySequence,
              completion: {
                if self.playerLost == false {
                    if self.score >= 1 {
                        self.enemy.removeFromParent()
                        self.scoreLabel.removeFromParent()
                        self.score += 1
                        self.setScore()
                        self.addEnemy()
                    } else {
                        self.score += 1
                        self.setScore()
                        self.enemy.removeFromParent()
                        self.addEnemy()
                    }


                }
    }
    )
}
```

copy enemy function:

```
func addEnemyCopy() {


    let enemyCopy = enemy.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(size.width - (enemy.size.width + 100))), y: 500)
    print("Enemy copy: ")
    print(enemyCopy.position)
    self.addChild(enemyCopy)
    let moveEnemy1 = SKAction.moveTo(y: player.position.y - 300, duration: 1)
    let deleteEnemy1 = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let enemySequence1 = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy1, deleteEnemy1])
    enemyCopy.run(enemySequence1,
                  completion: {
                    if self.playerLost == false {
                        if self.score >= 1 {
                            enemyCopy.removeFromParent()
                            self.scoreLabel.removeFromParent()
                            self.setScore()
                            self.addEnemyCopy()
                        } else {
                            self.setScore()
                            self.addEnemyCopy()
                        }

                    }
    }
    )

}
```

Not sure what other code I should put here, or if I should put all of it. Please feel free to ask in the comments to show more of the code.

Thanks! I know I can always count on Stack Overflow to help me!

Comment: "sometimes the two blocks were being spawned at a y value of 500"  Somestimes meaning depending on the device size?  Why are you setting magic numbers when there are several different device sizes?

Comment: @ElTomato, how do you know what he is doing.  It is ideal to only develop for 1 device size, that is what scaleMode is made for.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Where does that scaleMode property come from?  He doesn't mention it.

Comment: @ElTomato ... `SKScene`, no kidding he doesn't mention it.  Does not mean you assume he is automatically using `.resize` or he is designing based on screen size.  The default template is `.aspectFill` at a fixed size (Which is how people should be developing for most cases)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon  You are only making your own assumptions.

Comment: @ElTomato, I am not making any assumption,  you are the one telling him to do something that is wrong, I am telling you to not do that because you may end up making it worse for him.

Comment: @ElTomato for now I am only making this app for one device, I am not setting "magic" numbers...

Comment: @SavageProgrammer, if you are using the default SpriteKit template, then it will work the same on all 9:16 devices.  To handle other aspect ratios requires a little more trickery, but I have extensively covered that over many different questions here on SO.   The reason for that is because the default `scaleMode` is `.aspectFill` and the default scene size is iPhone 6.  The system will scale across any 9:16 device for you to fill the screen.  On 3:4 iPads, it will crop the top and bottom to get it to fit, and on iPhone X it will crop the sides to get it to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste failure:

```
func addEnemyCopy() {


    let enemyCopy = enemy.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    ****enemyCopy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(size.width - (enemy.size.width + 100))), y: 500)***
    print("Enemy copy: ")
    print(enemyCopy.position)
    self.addChild(enemyCopy)
    let moveEnemy1 = SKAction.moveTo(y: player.position.y - 300, duration: 1)
    let deleteEnemy1 = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let enemySequence1 = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy1, deleteEnemy1])
    enemyCopy.run(enemySequence1,
                  completion: {
                    if self.playerLost == false {
                        if self.score >= 1 {
                            enemyCopy.removeFromParent()
                            self.scoreLabel.removeFromParent()
                            self.setScore()
                            self.addEnemyCopy()
                        } else {
                            self.setScore()
                            self.addEnemyCopy()
                        }

                    }
    }
    )

}
```

I recommend using `refactor` more often.  That is, if you rename 1 variable, it will rename that variable anywhere that is attached to that declaration.

Comment: look at the ****** line

Comment: Sorry, just saw the CGPoint

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: Hey it happens, like I said, refactor. CTRL + Click a variable name to see the refactor context menu

Comment: Got it. Will use that from now on! Thanks <3